# How to Bulk-Remove All Hidden Devices in Device Manager? (Sample PowerShell Script for Single Devices)

Tags: windows, drivers, powershell

So a while back I put this together to clear devices and then re-scan:

```
$deviceName="Insert Device Name Here"
foreach ($dev in (Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq $deviceName})) {
  &"pnputil" /remove-device $dev.InstanceId 
}

pnputil.exe /scan-devices
```

I used it to deal with malfunctioning USB devices, I let this script run and it deleted every USB device it could find from Device Manager, and then re-scanned for hardware so connected devices would start working again. (It was great because this would even uninstall the mouse and keyboard drivers, and then reinstall them when it re-scanned; if I didn't do that then I'd have to force a restart which is never a good thing.)

Now I want to see about doing something else. I've read that sometimes drivers for "hidden" devices can cause problems if they get outdated, so I wanted to see if there was a way to use this (or something like this) to do that? It gets tedious having to do go through and do it manually by expanding every single category.

Comment: Device drivers do not go outdated (until Microsoft removes the APIs they use) and neither will this cause problems. Windows Update will update all drivers it can anyway.

Comment: Maybe so, but the fact remains that removing hidden devices has solved problems for me before, and all I'm looking to do is make the process simpler and faster.

Comment: Related but not an answer, switching Device Manager to `View by connection ` and then deleting the `USB Host controller ` is a one-step way to refresh all the child devices and have them re-detected...

Comment: @KeithMiller that's a capability I'd never known Device Manager had. Next time one of these problems pops up I'll give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the original script! It helped with neighbour's wireless device which is detected as a new instance each day polluting the device list.

Comment: @KonstantinPelepelin no problem! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer: https://github.com/istvans/scripts/blob/master/removeGhosts.ps1

This script has options that let you see "ghost" devices on your system without removing them, removing only certain of them (you can narrow it down by keyword), or removing them all. If anybody else has the same question as me this is how you do it.  I've tested it on two of my systems, one running Windows 10 and another running Windows 11, and it does the trick.